# can openstack set quota for one hypervisor

Tags: resources, limit, openstack, quota, hypervisor

Could I set some quota of one hypervisor like `memory_mb`?

I want to set the hypervisor's `memory_mb` to smaller than the true value -- **32126**, because I need to preserve some resource for the host's system running.

```
root@l-pc:~# openstack hypervisor show l-pc -c free_ram_mb -c memory_mb -c memory_mb_used -c running_vms
+----------------+-------+
| Field          | Value |
+----------------+-------+
| free_ram_mb    | 27518 |
| memory_mb      | 32126 |
| memory_mb_used | 4608  |
| running_vms    | 1     |
+----------------+-------+
root@l-pc:~# free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            31G        9.8G         17G        119M        3.9G         20G
Swap:           14G          0B         14G
```

I know there is a `openstack quota set` command can limit the resource for the project, but not for one hypervisor.

```
root@l-pc:~# openstack hypervisor -h
Command "hypervisor" matches:
  hypervisor list
  hypervisor show
  hypervisor stats show
```

Is there any method to achieve that like `openstack hypervisor set` for limit the resource consume in one hypervisor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "[reserved_host_memory_mb](https://docs.openstack.org/ocata/config-reference/compute/config-options.html)" parameter in **nova.conf**

> Any positive integer representing amount of memory in MB to reserve for the host.

Comment: THX, it's what I need. Now I could fond the relevant documentation because of your key parameter `reserved_host_memory_mb`.

Comment: it allows me to reserve memory for the host, but how to set it for the specific host?